# Generic foreach Loop in Javascript and AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm stuck with foreach loop , i don't know the column Name so i can't do 
`value.Job` ,   and i need to display all the colums with it specific data

```
angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
    console.log( 'the  Object N° ' + i );
    'maybe another loop for all the column
    console.log( 'the column name is + ': ' +  value ??);
});
```

the result should be like :

```
the  Object N° 1 
the column name is  Name  :  Matt 
the column name is  Job  :  Teacher

the  Object N° 2 
the column name is  Name  :  Alice
the column name is  Job  :  Doctor
```

Any ideas here !

I want to see both the options for JavaScript and AngularJs forEach.

Comment: Can you share a sample of how your data is structured?

Comment: What is the `i` var for?

Comment: where is the column name stored?

Comment: @Roysh - not according to angular docs

Comment: @user1187282 it looks that you're looking for loop in Angular to show your data

Comment: @user1187282: check my answer to do the same thing in Angular for each

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `for...in` loop to enumerate all the keys in an object as follows

```js
var data = [
  {Name: "Matt", Job: "Teacher"},
  {Name: "Alice", Job: "Doctor"}];

data.forEach(function(e,i){
  console.log(i);
  for(var key in e){
      console.log(key + ':' + e[key] ); 
  }
});
```

Note that ive used [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), but [`angular.forEach`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) will have much the same structure.

Comment: you're the best !!

Comment: @user1187282 awww, thanks. (BTW, I think that `for...in` can also be done with `angular.forEach` - it supports iterating an object too as I discovered by reading the docs)

Answer (score 1):

You may also try this:

```
data.forEach(function(item){
      Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key){
            console.log(key + ":" + item[key]);
      });
   });
```

Answer (score -1):

> Try following two options: **Generic JavaScript and AngularJs**

```js
//AngularJS for each 
var app = angular.module("app", []);
var values = [{'name': 'Jimi', 'gender': 'male'},{'name': 'Peter', 'gender': 'male'},{'name': 'Bob', 'gender': 'male'}];
app.controller('forEachController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.names = [];
        //Angular for each
        console.log("AngularJs Output");
        angular.forEach(values, function (value, key) {
            angular.forEach(value, function (val, k) {
              console.log(k + ":" + val);
            });
        });  
 }]);
console.log("JavaScript Output");
//Generic JavaScript for each
values.forEach(function(item){
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key){
    console.log(key + ":" + item[key]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="forEachController"></div>
```

Comment: It looks that question is asking to show angular for each to iterate data, that's why I've used Angular, Please justify downvote ?